# Paypal checkout - Identify customer / Append order ID

Tags: paypal, checkout

I am currently implementing paypal Checkout as per https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#

I can send payments etc no problem. However, how can I identify who made the payment?

```
 createOrder: function(data, actions) {
  // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
  return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
      amount: {
          value: '1.0'
      }
    }]
  });
}
```

.create does not allow me to append a order id or user id. In the paypal dashboard I can only see the name and the amount .

Answer (score 0):

In you `onApprove` function, inside `actions.order.capture(`:

```
console.log(data);
```

The information will be there for you.

You can see an example of it used for an alter in the demo here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client